# Django : __str__

Tags: python, django

-He visto muchos ejemplos de modelos en Django que utilizan **def __ str __** , pero como puedo utilizar exactamente esto, me explico, cual es el uso **EXACTO** de **def __ str __** .

-¿Las tablas no se encuentran si es que no se define la función **__ str __**?

Comment: SIMPLEMENTE: lo que hace es convertir eso en código binario
¿POR QUÉ?: bueno pues es mucho mejor para las computadora en código binario distribuir esa información.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Un método `__str__(self)` le dice a Python cómo mostrar la representación "string" de un objeto. Cuando creas una clase y le defines un método `__str__(self)`, por ejemplo:

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self,nombre,apellido):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.apellido=apellido
 
persona=Persona("Panchito","Gómez Toro")
print(persona)
```

Por ejemplo, imprime:

`<__main__.Persona object at 0x0000020B0787CA20>`

```
class Persona1:
    def __init__(self,nombre,apellido):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.apellido = apellido

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre + " " + self.apellido

persona1=Persona1("Panchito","Gómez Toro")
print(persona1)
```

Imprime:
`Panchito Gómez Toro`

Como sabes, Django es el framework, pero Python es el lenguaje. Por tanto, al implementar ese método en una clase de Django, se aplica el mismo procedimiento:

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField('nombre', max_length=140, blank=False)
    apellidos = models.CharField('apellidos', max_length=140, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre + " " + self.apellidos
```

Así, cuando muestres una instancia de la clase Persona (ya sea con print, en la lista de personas del admin de Django, etc), se mostrará con ese formato.
Si no lo defines, se mostraría, por ejemplo en la lista del admin de Django, con este formato:

`Persona object (el_pk_correspondiente_en_la_bd)`

Comment: Sin duda voto positivo, muy buena respuesta!!